# How to create data frame from list in R?

Tags: r, list, vector, dataframe

I have a list of 3000 vectors in R. How can I create a data frame from the first 1000 elements of this list?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
data.frame(myList[1:1000])
```

This makes the assumption that the vectors are all the same length.  If they are not, values will be recycled.